# Using Symbology to show count of points in Buffer with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.4

I'm pretty new to GIS and I'm using ArcGIS 10.4

I've gathered point information about two different variables, X and Y. I have created the buffer zone around the X points and used a spatial join to join the Y points within a .25 mile buffer around the X points.

How can I show the count of Y points inside this buffer using graduated symbols preferably?

[image]

Comment: Where is all the information stored? From your question I guess it is in the buffers. Do you have a picture of the attribute table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) to Join the points with the buffer polygon. Spatial Join can be found from `ArcToolbox -> Analysis Tools -> Overlay -. Spatial Join`.

[image]

Use Buffer feature as `Target Feature` and Y points as `Join Feature`, and in the `Field Map of Join Features`, right-click the target field and select `Merge rule`, then choose `Count`, and save the output shapefile as a new file.

[image]

You will get a new field in the attribute table with a name `Join_Count`, as you can see below:

[image]

Use the Join_Count field to symbolize the result based on graduated color not symbol, because graduated symbol works only with point feature not polygon feature.

[image]